# 3 month old new kitten not drinking water and looks always tired and sleepy

Tags: cats

Two days ago I got a male kitten(Bengal) that's 3 month old. Today particularly he started looking very tired and been sleeping the whole day. It doesn't seem fine and I will be taking him to the vet anyway in two days but was wondering if anyone could help on this since this is my first cat.

- He's been eating very little seen he got to his new home (am guessing he still needs to get used to it ?)
- He was pretty playful until today. Now he seems very tired and just wakes up to go and poop. Am not sure but he also looks sad a bit.
- He's not been drinking water...
- If I try to play with him he just walks away and turns his back.

**UPDATE**

On Sunday afternoon, after eating some cat wet food mixed with little cooked salmon, he started vomiting. He then had diarrhea (without blood in the stool). Until today he has received subcutaneous fluids because he keeps vomiting, no poo.

The vet thinks it can be an infection or intussusception of his bowels. They will try to take an xray tomorrow in a more specializes clinic to check for the latter.

I asked why not giving antibiotics as a preventive measure but the vet says that is the last resort.

He is now extremely weak and I wonder what can it be - and how long can he survive like this?

**Answer**
The kitten was diagnosed with coccidia after performing a fecal analysis.

Comment: Try to take him to the vet sooner.

Comment: @RonBeyer any reason in particular why you would say that ? do you seen any particular problem based on this behavior ?

Comment: Cats hide problems by nature, not drinking water and not urinating can be a sign of kidney issues, bladder infections, blockages, etc. Not being able to urinate is a serious issue. I've had two cats like that, the first one was in full blown renal failure by the time we got him to the vet, and cost thousands of emergency care. It may just be something simple, but why risk it?

Comment: Because cats hide problems, once you see the symptoms, it's an emergency, especially in the case of lethargy and not urinating. Waiting 2-3 days could result in you cancelling that appointment because you've lost the cat. ALWAYS treat symptoms like these as an emergency.

Answer (score 6):

**If it has gone on too long, rush the cat to the vet IMMEDIATELY.**

Cats, especially male cats, are prone to urinary tract infections (UTIs), and it can even become fatal very quickly. That is why it's a HUGE concern if the cat doesn't drink for long periods of time, or doesn't pee for long periods of time.

If the cat hasn't peed for twenty-four hours, then take it to an emergency vet immediately. If you see any specific signs of a UTI such as straining to pee, signs of pain while peeing, blood in the urine, peeing in tiny amounts, urinating outside the box, or frequent attempts to urinate, DO NOT WAIT. Take the cat to the emergency vet immediately.

It all may sound like a ridiculous hypereaction, but for cats it really can be a life or death situation. As an example of how real the danger is, the famous cat from internet memes known as "Grumpy Cat" [suddenly died from a UTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumpy_Cat).

**But if it isn't yet at the point that's its an emergency...**

It is true that cats when brought to a new home are often just too nervous to do basic things like drink or pee. If 24 hours have not yet passed, and you haven't observed any other UTI symptoms, try to limit the stress as much as possible by leaving it mostly on its own to settle in.

Some cats are really bad at drinking enough even when not under stress. For these cats, sometimes getting a bubbling cat fountain helps because they prefer moving water.  Or sometimes it's actually the bowl that is the problem.  Many cats don't like to drink or eat out of bowls. It's theorized it's because they don't like their whiskers to brush the sides.  So you might try giving its water in a very large and shallow bowl. If all else fails, then give the cat wet food, and mix in water into its food to force it to drink more that way.

Comment: And move the food and water dishes apart. Some cats don’t mind them being next to each other, others won’t drink where they eat.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes baby food of the strained meat variety will get cats to eat. If not they can be coaxed by putting the baby food on their lips and allowing them to lick it off.
Bottom line is you have to get some food and water into him. I lost a cat to UTI and I worked at Ohio State Vet Hosp. If he has a urinary plug it has to be cleared ASAP (NOW)If it keeps comming back he may require surgury. (Peritoneal Utherosomy)